# SQLPlus How to print the MAX of COUNT(*)?

Tags: sql, oracle

I need help in printing the department with the highest number of employees. Since, MAX(COUNT(*)) doesn't actually work, can anyone help me in this?

Say I have two tables named dept and emp, each of which have deptno and empdeptno respectively. 
I have this to count each employee in each department:

```
SELECT dept.deptname "Department",
    (SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM emp
     WHERE emp.empdeptno = dept.deptno) "Number of Employees"
FROM dept
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC;
```

How do you print the dept with the highest employee count without using LIMIT with the ORDER BY?

Comment: Why doesn't `max(count(*))` work? That's valid, with a suitable group by?

Comment: Have you tried ORDER BY "Number of Employees" DESC?

Comment: Just a hint: You help us help you if you provide us with the exact error. In your case, that might be something like "Unknown column 'COUNT()' in ORDER" or simply that you get value X, but that is not what you expected :-)

Comment: If the answer helped, you might accept it. That will also help people with the same problem to find a question that has been answered (your questions), and people looking for open questions to answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT dept.deptname "Department", COUNT(emp.empdeptno) AS "Number of Employees"
FROM dept
LEFT JOIN emp ON dept.deptno = emp.empdeptno
GROUP BY dept.deptname
ORDER BY COUNT(emp.empdeptno) DESC
```

You might consider `GROUP BY dept.UniqueDepartmentKey, dept.deptname` if dept.deptname is not the key and likely to be repeated.

You might need to refer to the alias: `GROUP BY "Department"`, depending on your SQL flavour.